# Hovering Div Elements

Tags: html, css

so i have a container div which holds 5 other divs (see picture ) and on hover those divs slide in the direction the arrow is pointed ( to right of picture ). I achieved this simply with CSS's :hover property. However, it achieved it's purpose but I simply just do not like the result ( see snippet ); certain mouse positions would cause the div to go back to the original position then back to hovered position again. Any ideas for improving the hover property?   Picture[image]

```css
body, html {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.body-container {
 position: fixed;
 overflow : hidden;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.ele-containers {
 width: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 transition: 0.6s;
 background: blue;
 border: 2px white solid;
}

#spring {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
#summer {
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
}

#winter {
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
}
#autumn {
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
}

#spring:before, #summer:before, #winter:before, #autumn:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

#spring:hover {
 left: -10%;
 top:-10%;
}
#winter:hover{
 left:-15%;
 top:65%;
}
#autumn:hover{
 left:65%;
 top:65%;
}

#summer:hover {
 left: 65%;
 top:-15%;
}




#spring:before {
 bottom: -100px;
 right: -100px;
}
#summer:before {
 bottom: -100px;
 left: -100px;
}
#winter:before {
 top: -100px;
 right: -100px;
}
#autumn:before {
 top: -100px;
 left: -100px;
}

#about-circle {
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 100%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 display: flex;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: linear-gradient(rgb(244, 217, 193), rgb(204, 230, 255));
 border: solid 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="body-container">

  <div class="ele-containers" id="spring">Spring</div>
  <div class="ele-containers" id="summer">Summer</div>
  <div class="ele-containers" id="winter">Winter</div>
  <div class="ele-containers" id="autumn">Autumn</div>
  <div class="circle-container" id="about-circle"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of moving the main `div`, you create pseudo elements and move them.

When done like that, it will solve the *hover* issue.

*Note, you might need to adjust the movement a little, I just made them up to show how-to*

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.body-container {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ele-containers {
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

#spring {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#summer {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

#winter {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

#autumn {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

#spring:before,
#summer:before,
#winter:before,
#autumn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  transition: 0.6s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

#spring:before {
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
  top: calc(100% - 100px);
}

#summer:before {
  top: calc(100% - 100px);
  left: -100px;
}

#winter:before {
  top: -100px;
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
}

#autumn:before {
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}

#spring:after,
#summer:after,
#winter:after,
#autumn:after {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.6s;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px white solid;
  transform-origin: left top;
  z-index: -1;
}


#about-circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(244, 217, 193), rgb(204, 230, 255));
  border: solid 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

#spring:hover::before,
#spring:hover::after {
  transform: translate(-30%,-15%);
}

#winter:hover::before,
#winter:hover::after {
  transform: translate(-15%,30%);
}

#autumn:hover::before,
#autumn:hover::after {
  transform: translate(30%,15%);
}

#summer:hover::before,
#summer:hover::after {
  transform: translate(30%,-15%);
}
```

```html
<div class="body-container">

  <div class="ele-containers" id="spring">Spring</div>
  <div class="ele-containers" id="summer">Summer</div>
  <div class="ele-containers" id="winter">Winter</div>
  <div class="ele-containers" id="autumn">Autumn</div>
  <div class="circle-container" id="about-circle"></div>
</div>
```